# Rails accessing all relations with deep nesting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested

I have the following models:

```
class Kid < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group, optional: true

class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :kids
  belongs_to :head

class Head < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :groups
  belongs_to :axis

class Axis < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :heads
```

What I've been trying to do is get all the kids of a head and of an axis (for example: @axis.kids would give all the kids, like @group.kids does).
I tried some class methods with loops and arrays, but no luck so far.
Any idea how to do this?
Thanks!

Using rails 5.2

Edit:
I got all the head's kids with

```
def kids
 Kid.where(group_id: self.groups.map(&:id))
end
```

But still haven't managed to get the axis' kids

Comment: You can add a relationship to Head  `has_many :kids, through: :groups` which will give you exactly what you want. I advise checking the official documentation when you have needs like this, because it is pretty common that you will find the answers there

Comment: Great, thanks.
How can I access @axis.kids?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Head you can add:

```
has_many :kids, through: :groups
```

Then you can do something like:

```
@head.kids
```

See the [Rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this:
has_many :kids, through: :heads
In axis.rb